# How to get value of function outside in separate value?

Tags: java

```java
public  void setAcc(String a)
{
  m_acc.setText(a);
}
```

I want to get the value of variable `a` as a separate variable outside this function.
The values of `a` are coming from another Controller Class.

Comment: Not understandable what you want ... what means "outside the class"? why not storing `a` in a class variable and provide a getter method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [*Writing the Perfect Question*](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) or at least his [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Some more code please. We cannot make anything out of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable outside of the method and change that variable inside the method.

```
private String acc; 

public void setAcc(String a)
{
    this.acc = a; 
    m_acc.setText(a);
}

...

System.out.println(acc); //prints the value of a
```